# How to join a string that has slashes + a variable in php?

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code:

```
$return = poster_curl( HOST, PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD, $_GET["image"], NULL, ptUNSPECIFIED );
```

I pass an image on the following way:

```
image.php?image=pic.jpg
```

It works on Linux, but I need it working on Windows. Unfortunately on Windows, I must specify the full path of the image. I tried to do like this:

`$return = poster_curl( HOST, PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD, 'C:\xampp\htdocs\images\examples' . $_GET["image"], NULL, ptUNSPECIFIED )`;

But I get this:

curl error=couldn't open file "C:\xampp\htdocs\images\examplespic.jpg"

If I put a reverse slash at the end of the path, like this:

`$return = poster_curl( HOST, PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD, 'C:\xampp\htdocs\images\examples\' . $_GET["image"], NULL, ptUNSPECIFIED )`;

It still doesn't work, I get this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 've' (T_STRING)
```

What is the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$return = poster_curl( …, 'C:\xampp\htdocs\images\examples\' . $_GET["image"], …
```

The backslash is *escaping* the `'`, so your string literal is unterminated … you have to *double* the last backslash here:

```
$return = poster_curl( …, 'C:\xampp\htdocs\images\examples\\' . $_GET["image"], …
```

Comment: Ohh got it. That was quick, problem solved. Thanks!!